# Android Studio Google Maps API v2

Tags: android-studio

i'm trying to use Google Maps API v2 in my project.
This is my environment:

- OSX 10.9
- Android Studio 0.3.2
- min SKD 9 and compile SDK 14
- Java 1.7.0_17
- Testing on Nexus 7 4.3 with GooglePlayService 4.0.30

I get the following errors on the device. Android Studio don‘t note any errors:

```
11-05 07:44:33.888    2386-2386/myproject E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find 
class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method 

myproject.activities.Maps.initMaps
11-05 07:44:34.052    2386-2386/myproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
                at myproject.activities.Maps.onResume(Maps.java:36)
```

The error point is clear: There are missing class files.

Here are the dependencies of my project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
}
```

In my opinion should be **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'** enough.
So any suggestions what's missing ?

Greetz,
Moddus

Comment: Did you install the "Android Support Repository" and "Google Repository" via Android SDK Manager (under "Extras" category)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
When I changed the version to `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'` my app started normally without any errors but the map was white. 
Tried several diferent api keys and still don't know where the problem is...

edit: Finally I made my app to shows up the map by changing the classpath of the buildsctipt. I'm using Android Studio v.0.4 which comes with gradle:0.7 and I gess it has a problems for now with google play services. Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```